# What is Oracle Advanced Compression?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

So i've read it somewhere it's about the capacity planning of the DB, and from what i read that it's about changing the DDL. So if i've already had the existing table, i'd have to alter the table.

I've read it from here [link](https://www.dummies.com/programming/databases/how-to-compress-data-in-oracle-12c/) it says like that.

```
<alter table emp move compress for all operations;>
```

So is it as simple as that? i just have to alter all my table using that alter script?
And will it be making any troubles in the future? like i have to adjust things? 
Because the table i'll alter that is the table for my Datawarehouse, and my job will do insert and update, or some DML to them.

Also i've heard about : 
 1. Null compression
 2. Value compression
 3. Compression between table

Is the 3 points above is the same as advanced compression?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle Advanced Compression is a package of utilities available for Oracle Database Enterprise Edition. It contains several features, however **BE CAREFULL** it is a licensed option, so it means you have to pay for it. If you only need to compress your tables in order to save storage, you can use basic compression. 
I would use Advanced Compression if my company can pay the added license needed because it is quite good and offers a lot of features. Remember always that compression is a trade-off between computation power and storage consumption.

Example

Basic compression

```
create table t1 ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(1) ) compress basic ;
```

Advanced compression

```
create table t2 ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(1) )  ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED;
```

Regarding altering a table to compress it, take in consideration the following:

I create a table without compression

```
create table t1 ( c1 number , c2 varchar2(1) ) nocompress ;
```

I insert records and records on it and then I alter the table

```
alter table t1 compress;
```

The command above does not compress the rows that were inserted before. It would only compress the data inserted afterwards. To compress the existing data

```
alter table t1 move compress;
```

Regards

Comment: I've tried and done that, and yes it shows the 'Bytes' size difference when i compare the before after using compression.And do you have any idea about these 1. Null compression 2. Value compression 3. Compression between table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the different compression possibilities in the [concepts guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-54EE5325-0894-4869-B3AD-8912D9B4A329). Converting a table from non-compressed to compressed is as simple as you stated. It might take some time though, depending on the size of the table.
If this is a DWH, and you seldom update the data, you can use 'basic compression' without any additional cost. You may also use it only on big fact tables and not small dimension ones.

Comment: So the compression won't change or won't make any future problems ? Like i added a partition into my table, and if the data didn't match partition condition i.e. the data has larger values than my partition it will reject the data. But will it do the same like compression will reject the data ? or it will make the null values vanish or something? 
Thankyou..

Comment: Partitioning has nothing to do with compression, you can compress some partition and not all of them. Rows you insert should go into the proper partition, and if that does not exist, you get an error (if you don't have a default partition). Compression has no impact on how the DB handles NULL values.

Comment: @PiPio, Partitioning has nothing to do with compression at all. Compression willl only make the data to consume less storage. However, there are some aspects you need to take in consideration. For example, compression will not allow you to drop a column of a table, in that case you will need to uncompress, moving the table, drop the column, compress and moving back the table

Comment: Basic compression will not allow dropping columns, the other types do allow.